# Issue with entity framework migration. [Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using EF code first and asp.net MVC. Here is my technical stack.

1. Visual Studio 2010
2. Entity Framework 4.3.1

In my migrations folder, I can see three migrations files are existing.

1. InitialCreate
2. AddStandardException
3. DocumentScope

When I check my database I can see that `_MigrationHistory` table has all three migrations applied. Now I have added one more DbSet, and I want to write migrations for it. When I attempt to give this command

```
Add-Migration NewTable
```

It gives me this error :

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201402121621095_AddStandardException, 201402190713571_DocumentScope]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

I don't understand why is it complaining about pending migrations whereas all migrations have been applied?

How do I even troubleshoot this ? I tried with `-Debug` switch but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to it. I have just commented code inside the Up() and Down() functions. Then ran Update-Database. It applied some dummy migrations and then reported that

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

After this when i ran

Add-Migration NewTable

It gave me the correct result. Any idea whats going on here ?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to run "`update-database`" from the package manager console to push your changes to the database OR you can delete the pending migration file ([201402121621095_AddStandardException]) from your Migrations folder and then re-run "add-migration" to create a brand new migration based off of your edits.

Answer (score -3):

**Explanation**: "update-database" basically modifies existing table fields while "add-migration" works like git by making a snapshot of the distinct model changes. These snapshots show how the database evolved over time so they are more useful to your code user than the EF or the App itself. 
That being said, it is possible that your newer classes have a quite different code signature which may not "flow" with the existing classes.
**Solution:** Modify or remove the previous migrations since the new migration will create a new data structure that won't use or need them